# Contrib module service overriding not working

Tags: 9, redirection, services

I am using the ‘Path Redirect Import module along with the Redirect module.
I am trying to override its service ‘path_redirect_import.importer’
To do this, I have added a service provider and a custom class that extends the service class that I want to override.
however, the overridden function is not getting called.
Followed [this](https://rikdeboer.medium.com/a-drupal-module-for-overriding-services-8732699c1a20) tutorial:

Any suggestions?

1. inside my custom module's src folder, I created MyModuleServiceProvider.php, which contains the following:

   namespace Drupal\my_module;

   ```
    use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
    use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceModifierInterface;
    use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase;


    class MyModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase implements ServiceModifierInterface {

      public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {

        if ($container->hasDefinition('path_redirect_import.importer')) {
          $definition = $container->getDefinition('path_redirect_import.importer');
          $definition->setClass('Drupal\my_module\MyTestProv');
        }

      }

    }
   ```

in the MyTestProv.php

```
namespace Drupal\my_module;


use Drupal\path_redirect_import\ImporterService;

/**
 * Class ImporterService.
 *
 * @package Drupal\path_redirect_import
 */
class MyTestProv extends ImporterService {
  public static function import($file, array $options) {
    // If I put something here nothing happens
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t('Lorem ipsum.'));
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is different to what you posted in Slack. The first problem is that if the module namespace is my_module then the ServiceModifierInterface implementation must be named MyModuleServiceProvider, not UelCoreServiceProvider.

Comment: I wanted to sound a bit generic here. Fixed the class name here. Is there any other issue apart from that?

Comment: Are you sure a flash message is the best way to validate this is called? Is this your actual code?